# how do i make a menu to load other files in ruby

Tags: ruby

I am learning to code in ruby.
so I made a couple simple games, and now I want to make a menu to select which one to load.
My question is, how do I, from the menu.rb load the game1.rb?

I tried to use require_relative game1.rb, and kind of work, but if from the game i go back to the menu to select another game, the menu stops working.

my code is like this:

puts " 1 - game 1"
puts " 2 - game 2"
puts " 0 - exit"

loop do
  puts "which game to load?"
  chose = gets.to_i
  case chose
    when 1
      require_relative 'game1'
    when 2
      require_relative 'game2'
    when 0
      system('cls')
      abort
    else
      puts "not a valid input"
  end
end

thanks for the help... :D
(sorry for any mistakes,  I'm also learning English and is my first time here)

Answer (score 0):

You can use built-in function `load`. For example if you want to include `b.rb` in file `a.rb` then in `a.rb` you can use `load('b.rb')`. More information found here 
https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Kernel.html#method-i-load

Comment: Depending on how the file to load is written, `require` instead of `load` might be the correct way, if we consider the possibility that - in the same run - the user might want to play the same game again. Imagine that the file to be included contains a constant definition. Loading the same file again would cause a *already initialized constant* warning.

Comment: The problem that I'm having whit require is when I load the menu.rb the first time it works, but once i load a game, and from the game I use the require to go back to the menu, stop working, the thing star an infinite loop asking me which game to load.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I just tried with load, and works just like i wanted, thanks sriharsha_bhat and  user1934428.